Static Form Input Value Not allow to change input value entered by the user
I'm working on a React application where I'm navigating from a Task component to a PersonDetails component, and I'm encountering issues with updating and reflecting form data correctly.
I am only focusing on the name input field, so that user can change its value, while I am passing static values from the parent component
Here is a snippet of the relevant code:
Task Component:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import PersonDetails from './PersonDetails';

export default function Task() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let [formData, setformData] = useState({
    uName: '',
    uGender: '',
    uMedals: 0,
  });
  let [submitData, setsubmitData] = useState([]);

  let handleForm = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name === 'uMedals') {
      value = parseInt(value);
      if (value <= 0) {
        value = 0;
      }
      if (value > 20) {
        value = formData.uMedals;
      }
    }
    setformData((formData) => ({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  let handleUpdate = (indexNumber) => {
    let updatedRow = submitData[indexNumber];
    setformData({
      uName: updatedRow.uName,
      uGender: updatedRow.uGender,
      uMedals: updatedRow.uMedals,
    });
    navigate('/PersonDetails', { state: { formData } });
  };

  return (
    <div className='parent-container'>
      {/* Form and other UI elements */}
      <PersonDetails
        handleForm={handleForm}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

PersonDetails Component:

import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function PersonDetails({
  handleForm,
  handleSubmit,
}) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const {formData} = location.state
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className='parent-container'>
        <h1 className='h-pDetail'>PersonDetails</h1>
        <div className='content-wrapper'>
        <div className='left parent-det'>
          <form className='form-wrapper' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className='name-wrapper'>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='uName'
                onChange={handleForm}
                value={formData.uName}
                pattern='[A-Za-z]*'
                style={{ padding: ' 5px' }}
              />
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>


So... are you wanting to render PersonDetails in Task and pass those props down, or are you wanting to render PersonDetails on a route and navigate and pass route state to it? You can basically do one or the other. Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish and what the specific problem is. I invite you to also take the full [tour] and to review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Also, FWIW, React state updates are not immediately processed nor do they change the state value in the scope of a callback, so calling setformData(....) and then immediately trying to pass formData in route state on the next line won't pass the next state value you are updating to.

I created a form in Task.js component and when user click on update button to update the form, I am just trying to navigate the form to the personDetails. where the person details is already shown in the form with update button but when the user want to update the form, the form in personDetails doesnot allow to even change the values of input field (like: name). I think there is an issue in handleform, which is not updating the state value . I want to pass value from personDetails  to Task.js component through handle form function

I am stuck with that, any help is appreciated

FWIW, if you are using PersonDetails as a child component then I see no issue with the handleForm callback. I suspect the problem you are seeing is the input in PersonDetails no updating because it's trying to use some location.state.formData.uName value as the input value be given the code you have shared this value is either undefined, or is some value and unlikely to change because no navigation actions are involved in editing the field value. So are you just wanting to render PersonDetails as a child component of Task?

I want to send the updated value back to task component by using their state (task component state: setformdata), to update values in input field in personDetail component.

The handleForm callback already does that though. The input in PersonDetails calls handleForm when the input value changes and handleForm updates the state in Task.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
